# Spring Cloud Stream Binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Any ideas would be appreciated, I am trying write test as;

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(count = 1, controlledShutdown = true, topics = { "input", "output" }, brokerProperties = { "broker.id=2",
    "listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092" })
class BindingTest {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

@Autowired
private CustomBindings cBindings;

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws Exception {
    embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers().forEach(b -> b.shutdown());
}

@Test
void test0() {
    String KEY = "KEY";
    String testMessage = "TESTMESSAGE";
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(testMessage)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, KEY).build();
    cBindings.output().send(message);

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(CustomBindings.class)
public static class BindingApplication {

}
```

}

and

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/json

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.header-mode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.use-native-encoding=true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.keySerde==org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.valueSerde==org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Still gets

error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@71f0806b]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[8], headers={id=c91897bc-2e4e-0a74-bc05-17fb31b690f6, kafka_messageKey=KEY, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1542295539746}]

Which doesnt make sense to me

Comment: I believe you need to set `useNativeDecoding` to true since you're choosing to use native Kafka serde. See more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, this is not a Kafka Streams application, but a regular Spring Cloud Stream application with the Kafka binder. Therefore, you don't need these two properties.

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.keySerde==org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.valueSerde==org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer`

In addition, in order to fix your error, you need to remove this line from your config: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.use-native-encoding=true`.

By setting native encoding to true, you are asking Kafka to do the serialization which is going to rely on the default `ByteArraySerializer`. If you really intended native serialization, you need to set the appropriate value serializer (`StringSerializer`). But since this is a test, I suggest you remove this property and see if your test passes.

Comment: Hello, I know it's completely different but since these are producer proerpties, is there a way to set these properties via ProducerProperties and if so what is the property for use-native-encoding

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. `use-native-encoding` is set on the producer as a producer property. For e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.use-native-encoding`. This is explained above in the answer.